# Angular Material Drag and Drop cdkDragConstrainPosition not scoped to component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am using CDK drag and drop in my project. Inside the method: cdkDragConstrainPosition I am computing a 'snap' to columns in my component. When this method is called, I can't access any of my component level variables. They are all undefined. When I do `console.log(this)` it outputs `DragRef` so the scope set to the component. How can I access my component level variables inside this function?

```
<div cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary=".drag-boundary" [cdkDragData]="{'colwidth': colWidth}" [cdkDragConstrainPosition]="computeDragRenderPos" [style.width.px]="colWidth" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(80px, 177px, 0px); background-color: beige; top: 0; left: 0; height: 42px; overflow: hidden">
    <div>Chris's awesome presentation. Doing fun stuff with science</div>
  </div>
```

Relevant Component code:

```
computeDragRenderPos(pos, dragRef, clientRect) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.myComponentVariable); //this is undefined

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `cdkDragConstrainPosition` accepts function as a parameter and not a value. So the function is called in the scope of directive that uses it as an input, hence `this` is not your component. You can define your function using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to preserve the scope. Try something like this (from the top of my head):

```
computeDragRenderPos = (userPointerPosition: Point, dragRef: DragRef,
  dimensions: ClientRect): Point => {
      //console.log(this.myComponentVariable);
}
```